# Optimal design for constrained Bayesian slope intercept model

Tags: calculus, statistics, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Here is a problem I've been stuck on for quite a while.
Consider the model
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{H}\pmb{ \theta }+\pmb{\epsilon }.
\end{equation}
The design matrix is given by:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{H}\pmb{}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1&t_{1}\\
\vdots&\vdots\\
1&t_{m}\\
\end{array}
\right),
\end{equation}
where $0\leq t_j\leq T$. The parameter vector is given by:
\begin{equation}
\pmb{\theta }\sim \mathcal{N}\left(\pmb{\mu},\mathbf{C}_{\theta}\right),
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{C}_{\theta}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\delta_1^2&0\\
0&\delta_2^2\\
\end{array}\right).
\end{equation}
Assume that the errors are distributed as follows:
\begin{equation}
\pmb{\epsilon }\sim \mathcal{N}\left(\pmb{0},\mathbf{C}_{\epsilon}\right),
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{C}_{\epsilon}=\sigma^2\pmb{I}.
\end{equation}
For this model, the inverse of the between-subjects covariance matrix is given by:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{C}_{\theta}^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{\delta_1^2}&0\\
0&\frac{1}{\delta_2^2}\\
\end{array}\right).
\end{equation}
Furthermore, the response BMSE (i.e., the BMSE of a model prediction at some $t_{j^*}$ which is also between $0$ and $T$) is given by

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{M}_{\hat{f}_{j^*}}=\mathbf{h}'\left(\mathbf{C}_{\theta}^{-1}+\mathbf{H}'\mathbf{C}_{\epsilon}^{-1}\mathbf{H}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{h},
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{h}$ is the covariate vector at the time at which we want to make predictions:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{h}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
t_{j^*}\\
\end{array}\right),
\end{equation}
 and let $j^*$ denote the index of a response $y_{j^*}$ at some future time $t_{j^*}$.

I would like to prove that when
\begin{equation}
\frac{t_{j^*}(\frac{\sigma^2}{m}+\delta_1^2)}{\delta_1^2}>T,
\end{equation}
then $\mathbf{M}_{\hat{f}_{j^*}}$ is minimized inside the feasible region by collecting data at times such that $t_1=\dots=t_m=T$.

Was able to prove this result for the case of two data points, but having a lot of trouble generalizing it to m data points.

Comment: To lazy to write out a solution now, have a look at:  http://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/~gwoodwor/AdvancedDesign/Chaloner%20Verdinelli.pdf       or    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_experimental_design     and its references.